# How to insert the newly Created HTML String just after the </header> section

Tags: jquery

I have a Header Section as shown below

```
  <header>
       <div class="my-items">
          <i class="my-cart"></i>
          <div>1</div>
       </div>
       <h1>My Cart</h1>
    </header>
```

I want to insert the newly Created HTML String just after the  section 
So that it looks as

```
<header>
   <div class="my-items">
      <i class="my-cart"></i>
      <div>1</div>
   </div>
   <h1>My Cart</h1>
</header>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8ypx7tu/1/

I have tried as using insertAfter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var htmlStr = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>';
    $(htmlStr).insertAfter(".my-cart");
});
```

Rather than appending , i want to use .html() so that it replaces if anything is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `insertAfter('header')`

```js
var htmlStr = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>';
$(htmlStr).insertAfter('header:has(.my-cart)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="my-items">
    <i class="my-cart"></i>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <h1>My Cart</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks , can i match the header and the class ? (i mean the selector )

Comment: @Lavanya you can use `has` filter. check updated answer

Comment: will this be same as .html() , will it replaces ? or just appends ?

Comment: so its not possible to use .html() with after insertAfter

Comment: It's possible but not with  `insertAfter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can change to use `after` as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var htmlStr = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>';
    $('header').after(htmlStr);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var htmlStr = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>';
    $('header').after(htmlStr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   <div class="my-items">
      <i class="my-cart"></i>
      <div>1</div>
   </div>
   <h1>My Cart</h1>
</header>
```